# Split an array column into chunks of max size

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, slice, chunks

I have a DataFrame with one column of array[string] type.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- user: string (nullable = true) ### this is an unique key 
 |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Due to some limitations on the consumer's side, I need to limit the number of elements in the `items` column, e.g: to maximum 1000 elements. The outcome DataFrame would have the same schema, except there's no uniqueness on the `items` column anymore. For example, with max elements = 3:

Input DataFrame:

```
+----+----------------------+
|user|items                 |
+----+----------------------+
|u1  |[a, b, cc, d, e, f, g]|
|u2  |[h, ii]               |
|u3  |[j, kkkk, m, nn, o]   |
+----+----------------------+
```

Output DataFrame:

```
+----+------------+
|user|items       |
+----+------------+
|u1  |[a, f, g]   |
|u1  |[b, cc, d]  |
|u1  |[e]         |
|u2  |[h, ii]     |
|u3  |[j, nn, m]  |
|u3  |[kkkk, o]   |
+----+------------+
```

The order of items is not important.
The value of each item is just a string of alphanumeric chars, but the size of each item is not fixed.

Performance is not an issue, the DataFrame is small but we need the solution in SparkSQL.

Comment: I think you are looking for this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072321/split-row-into-multiple-rows-to-limit-length-of-array-in-column-spark-scala

Comment: Thanks. It works. Would you mind putting this as an answer to my question?

Comment: Sure!! I am glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

This can be worked out without higher-order functions, in three easy steps:

1. [`posexplode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode.html) the arrays of items
2. take integral part from dividing item's `pos` by N, the desired number of elements in subarrays
3. [`collect_list`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html) new arrays grouping by `user` and `pos`.

For N=3:

```
    >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ... {'user':'u1','items':['a', 'b', 'cc', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']},
    ... {'user':'u2','items':['h', 'ii']},
    ... {'user':'u3','items':['j', 'kkkk', 'm', 'nn', 'o']}
    ... ])
    >>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    >>> df1 = df.select(posexplode(df.items),df.user)
    >>> df2 = df1.select(floor(df1.pos/3).alias('pos'),df1.col.alias('item'),df1.user)
    >>> df3 = df2.groupby([df2.user,df2.pos]).agg(collect_list(df2.item)).drop('pos')
    >>> df3.show(truncate=False)
    +----+------------------+                                                       
    |user|collect_list(item)|
    +----+------------------+
    |u2  |[h, ii]           |
    |u1  |[a, b, cc]        |
    |u1  |[d, e, f]         |
    |u1  |[g]               |
    |u3  |[nn, o]           |
    |u3  |[j, kkkk, m]      |
    +----+------------------+
    
    >>>
```

Comment: Thanks. What a nice trick.
Between using high-order functions and this, what would you recommend?
Thanks

Comment: `transform` will create and execute your lambdafunction as mini-UDF :)) The alternative above will involve a shuffle, but is open to further catalyst optimizations if this step is part of a larger execution plan. So depends on what you are after, I guess, but using `explain` and comparing output would probably give you a good idea.